# Randomize Slurm Node Allocation

Tags: linux, cluster, hpc, job-scheduler, slurm

Has anyone had luck randomizing Slurm node allocations? We have a small cluster of 12 nodes that could be used by anywhere from 1-8 people at a time with jobs of various size/length. When testing our new Slurm setup, jobs always go to the first node in the partition if there are no other users for both interactive and batch jobs. Is there a way to randomize this scheduling?

It seems like, depending on a user's timeline, they could consistently get the same nodes and this could disguise issues in hardware/configuration that might otherwise be visible. Our nodes are always exclusive, so we're only looking at randomizing the node-level scheduling...

Answer (score 2):

Look at the Weight setting in slurm.conf

> The priority of the node for scheduling purposes. All things being
>   equal, jobs will be allocated the nodes with the lowest weight which
>   satisfies their requirements. For example, a heterogeneous collection
>   of nodes might be placed into a single partition for greater system
>   utilization, responsiveness and capability. It would be preferable to
>   allocate smaller memory nodes rather than larger memory nodes if
>   either will satisfy a job's requirements. The units of weight are
>   arbitrary, but larger weights should be assigned to nodes with more
>   processors, memory, disk space, higher processor speed, etc. Note that
>   if a job allocation request can not be satisfied using the nodes with
>   the lowest weight, the set of nodes with the next lowest weight is
>   added to the set of nodes under consideration for use (repeat as
>   needed for higher weight values). If you absolutely want to minimize
>   the number of higher weight nodes allocated to a job (at a cost of
>   higher scheduling overhead), give each node a distinct Weight value
>   and they will be added to the pool of nodes being considered for
>   scheduling individually. The default value is 1.

Answer (score 1):

You can add "LLN=YES" to the partition.

> LLN
>   Schedule resources to jobs on the least loaded nodes (based upon the number of idle CPUs).

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that it is possible to randomize node allocation without altering the code or providing your own plugin. There are many way to affect which nodes will be chosen by a given job, but none of them are random. As @Tux_DEV_NULL noted you can use weight to prefer a subset of nodes, but unless you're randomly changing weights you'll still end up on the same node again and again if your entire cluster is idle. I believe that a nodes uptime is used as the ultimate tie breaker.

If you're worried about missing misconfigured or broken nodes then you should use a node health check script using the HealthCheckProgram parameter in slurm.conf. A good one to use can be found here:
https://github.com/mej/nhc